# jQuery, displaying the text inside an input if the input text has more than two characters works more than once. (Every two characters)

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, input, text

I have a jQuery function that I want to be executed when a text input field has more than two characters:

```
$('#textInput').on('input', displaySuggestions);

function displaySuggestions(){
    if($('#textInput')[0].value.length > 2){
        let searchValue = $('#textInput')[0].value;
        $.myObj.getResults( searchValue, (results) => {            
          console.log(results); 
      });
    }
}
```

The function works good if I don't use the getResults function, which I need. It is from a plugin that looks like this:

```
(function($) {

    $.myObj = {

        getResults: function(value, callBack){
            var req = $.ajax({
                url:'http://api.my/api/name' + value
            });

             req.done(callBack);
        }
    };

}(jQuery));
```

The function should log the results which is  JSON data from the api call. It should return the results only once, when there are more than two characters added in the text input field. However when using the getResults function, the results are logged every two characters, for example, If I write a word with six letters, the results will be logged 3 times. I am not allowed to make changes in the getResults function, but if there is no fix around it, I would consider. Not sure how to wrap my head around it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the results only once ever then use the corresponding off method to remove the handler.

```
function displaySuggestions(){
    if ($('#textInput')[0].value.length > 2) {
        let searchValue = $('#textInput')[0].value;
        $.myObj.getResults( searchValue, (results) => {            
          console.log(results); 
      });
      $('#textInput').off('input', displaySuggestions);
    }
}
```

If you want to call the results each time the input exceeds 2 characters (e.g. user deletes input and retypes), then add a guard around the getResults() call.

```
let displayResults = true;
function displaySuggestions() {
    let searchValue = $('#textInput')[0].value;
    if (displayResults) {
        if (searchValue.length > 2) {
            displayResults= false;
            $.myObj.getResults( searchValue, (results) => {
                console.log(results); 
            });
        }
    } else if (searchValue.length < 2) {
        displayResults = true;
    }
}
```